# Selecting a specific value within a case statement

Tags: sql

I need help with selecting a specific value within a CASE Statement.

For an example

```
SELECT CASE WHEN Field1 >= (Field2 = 1) THEN Answer
            WHEN Field1 <  (Field2 = 1) THEN No Answer
            ELSE Question END AS Field3
```

I want to be able to select a specific value in Field2 within the CASE Statement

Comment: Please add some rows of sample data and the expected result. A few rows of data can help us understand what you want.

Comment: What's the database?

Comment: That's a case _expression_, not statement.

Comment: You need to quote the string literals, e.g. `'No Answer'`.

Comment: Tables have _columns_, not fields...

Answer (score 0):

could be you are looking for

```
 SELECT CASE WHEN Field1 >=  Field2 AND Field2 = 1 THEN Answer
        WHEN Field1 < Field2 AND Field2 = 1 THEN No Answer
        ELSE Question END AS Field3
```

or more simply

```
 SELECT CASE WHEN Field1 >=   1 THEN Answer
        WHEN Field1 < 1 THEN No Answer
        ELSE Question END AS Field3
```

Answer (score 0):

```
-- 1. You don't specify the fields types.
-- 2. You do a comparison of Field1 with a logical expression (Field2=1). i guess it fails.
-- 3. I will assume Answer, No answer and Question will be the desired string result, and have to be quoted.
-- 4. A Table name is missing. I will assume Field1 and Field2 are fields from MyTable
-- 5. I' am assuming Field1 and Field2 of the same type, and be varchar(10) for example.

DECLARE @Field2 varchar(10) = 1

SELECT 
        CASE    WHEN Field1 >= Field2   THEN 'Answer'
                WHEN Field1 <  Field2   THEN 'No Answer'
                                        ELSE 'Question'
        END AS Field3
FROM    MyTable
WHERE   Field2 = @Field2
```